# Kentico delivered to multiple browsers

Tags: kentico

How do I get Kentico to use different templates based on differing browsers, yet use the same content?

I need to deliver the same content to both IE9+ in HTML5, but also have a version that works on IE8 that doesn't use HTML5.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Kentico are you using or planning on using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see this [thread](http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums.aspx?forumid=47&threadid=19174) it still applies.

However, have you considered using [conditional layouts](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/page_layouts.htm#conditional_layouts)?